# SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE within the same query using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, query-optimization

I am wandering if it is possible to first SELECT and if not true INSERT into db within the same query using mysqli?

Here is how I do i now:

```
$sel_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j")-$day, date("Y"));
$sel_tag = date("Y-m-d",$sel_timestamp);
$user = 1;

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."_active_users WHERE userid = $user AND DATE(timestamp) = '$sel_tag'")){

    if($result->num_rows < 1){

        $insert = "INSERT INTO ".$prefix."_active_users (userid,timestamp) VALUES (?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

        if($stmt->prepare($insert)){
            $stmt->bind_param('is', $user,$sel_tag);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->close(); 
        }
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

In my case I use 2 queries, but is it possible to merge this into one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `table schema of "$prefix."_active_users`. And why do you insert timestamp against a userid?

Comment: It is for statistics... Active unique users pr. day.

Table schema: userid
int(11)
NO
MUL
NULL
timestamp
timestamp
NO
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: confusing... Can't understand.

Comment: how about calling a stored procedure ??

Answer (score 0):

if you have a UNIQUE KEY on (userid,timestamp), then you can use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ".$prefix."_active_users (userid,timestamp) VALUES (?,?)
```

IGNORE is a key word

However, you can leave your current code as is. Nothing wrong with having 2 queries too.

Comment: I am trying to optimize my site and I have to many queries,,, How does your example get rit of the SELECT query?